# Java: "myString[hey, there]" to HashSet?

Tags: java, arrays, string, hashset

I had a HashSet and i stored the content of it in a String using .toString(). Is there any simple way to get the String back into a HashSet?

I saved some configurations for a program in a textfile, and now i'm trying to read the config.

I could probably do it by removing the first and the last characters [ ], and then just split it using split(). And then loop through and add it to a HashSet. But it feels like a big detour, there should be an opposite to .toString()?

So, is there any simpler way than the way i described?

Comment: And even then it will not work if one of element contains a comma

Comment: Instead of storing the output of `toString()`, consider using JSON.

Comment: I am deleting my answer because obviously the solution is to use a better way of doing marhsalling to disk rather than just `toString()` but you rather give me -1 points for writing 'text files' because I was quoting the author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `toString()` is not a conversion methods and classes usually don't implement a `static fromString` method. So what you describe is the simplest way.

Note that it will not reconstruct the Set correctly if the elements themselves contain `comma` character.

Answer (score 2):

you will have to write a primitive parser, which will parse your string and reconstruct your configuration objects